# Create a class that extends the java.io.PrintStream class

Tags: java

I have a problem in java that I am having trouble solving, here it is:
Create a class named **WebPrintStream** that descends from **java.io.PrintStream**.
The class must work with the following constructor:
**WebPrintStream (OutputStream out, Boolean flush)**

The values passed in parameters must be supplied to the
constructor of the parent class.

Create the **printbr ()** method which accepts a value as a parameter, converts it to a **String** (if necessary) and displays its content in **OutputStream** by appending the string and a line break. To do this you can use the **println ()** and / or **print ()** of its parent class. (In other words, you don't need to work
directly on the **OutputStream** object).

Like the methods of the parent class **println ()** and **print ()**, your **printbr ()** method must support the following types for the value passed in parameter: **String**, **boolean**, **long**, **char**,
**char []**, **float**, **double**, **object**, **int**.
Here is the code to complete:

```
public class ExerciseImpl {

    public void runExercise (String [] argv) throws Exception {
        // this variable will be filled at runtime
        WebPrintStream wp = new WebPrintStream (System.out, true);
        wp.printbr ("blah");

    }

}
/ *
 * Create a class named WebPrintStream which descends from java.io.PrintStream.
 * The class must work with the following constructor WebPrintStream (OutputStream out, boolean flush).
 * Create the printbr () method which accepts a value as a parameter , converts it to a String (if necessary)
 * and displays its contents in OutputStream by appending the string [it] <br/> [/ it] and a line break.
 * The method must support the following types for the value passed in parameter: String, boolean, long, char, char [], float, double, object, int
 * /

/ * ---------- DO NOT MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET ON RUN ---------- * /

/ **** Enter your code here **** /

/ * ---------- DO NOT CHANGE THE CODE BELOW THIS LINE, IT WILL BE RESET WHEN RUNNING ---------- * /
```

Voici le code que j'ai proposé pour la classe **WebPrintStream**:

```
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class WebPrintStream extends PrintStream {

     @override
    public WebPrintStream(PrintStream out, boolean flush) {
        
    }
     @override
    public void printbr(String string) {
        
        
    }

}
```

this is the code I am proposing for the WebPrintStream class but I know that it is not complete at all and for the **printbr ()** method, I do not know how to express this sentence in java code: "your **printbr ()** method must support the following types for the value passed in parameter: **String**, **boolean**, **long**, **char**,
**char []**, **float**, **double**, **object**, **int**."

Do you have a solution for me please?

Comment: Hi, perhaps extend the class with `public class WebPrintStream extends PrintStream`, and annotate the overriden methods with `@Override`

Comment: yes i did it and now what about the body of the overriden method?how should i complete them?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

```
   import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

public class WebPrintStream extends PrintStream {


    public WebPrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean autoFlush) {
        super(out, autoFlush);
    }

    public void printbr(Object obj) {

        this.print(obj);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebPrintStream webPrintStream = new WebPrintStream(System.out, true);
        webPrintStream.print("bah");
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok why super(out,autoFlush)? and not super(out,flush) what is autoFlush?

Comment: mistake:  public WebPrintStream(OutputStream out, boolean flush) {
        super(out, flush);
    }

Comment: yes it works,what about the body of the printbr( ) method?how can i write that body?and then what about the body of WebPrintStream( ) méthode?how can i write it also?